# How 'Exclude URLs With regex' In Live HTTP headers

Tags: regex

I want to exclude some urls from Live HTTP headers (firefox add-on).
so in `Config` area i checked  `Exclude URLs With regex` and put the string below in it:

```
.gif$|.jpg$|.ico$|.css$|.js$|.png$|.bmp$|.jpeg$|google$|bing$|alexa$
```

i want to remove all images from capturing and any url that contains :
`css - js - google - bing - alexa`
what is the problem about my regex and would you please fix it for me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `.` means *"any char"*
- `$` means *"the end of the string"*

That said:

- `.gif$` will match *"any string ending with `gif` that is at least 4-char long"*
- `google$` will match *"any string ending with `google`"*

I guess you were looking for something like:

```
[.](gif|jpg|ico|css|js|png|bmp|jpeg)$|\b(google|bing|alexa)\b
```

Maybe your regexps get autoanchored with `^` and `$` by the tool you're using. In this case, use `.*` additionally:

```
.*[.](gif|jpg|ico|css|js|png|bmp|jpeg)$|.*\b(google|bing|alexa)\b.*
```

Comment: thanks for the answer / would you please show me how can i have (containing a string)?

Comment: @MoonLight Just put the string: `google`. If you want to match only the word: `\bgoogle\b` (strings like `foogooglebar` won't match then). Maybe the tool you're using autoanchors the regex with `^` and `$`, see my edit.